# How to update main{} when threads are finished?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

For purely thread-learning purposes, I'm trying to create a simulation of a slot machine.

3 reels which are 3 separate threads. They wait a random amount of time, then come up with a randomized number between 1 and 9.

I've been successful with this so far, however, **how do I properly let main{} know when all 3 reels are "done", so CheckJackpot() can be ran, which can then restart the game (threads) to do it all over again?**

I tried setting up a bool "isFinished" in the reels and had main check it in a while(true), but that completely recks my cpu. I came a step closer by adding a sleep timer in the loop, though I can tell how this is sloppy coding, even if it will work in my small experiment. Every reel will then also need a while(true) to check up if the isFinished goes back to false to restart the game I imagine.

I have learned about lock statements, however I don't believe this is the proper solution for what I wish to achieve. I have a feeling I need to learn about "events", though it may be way over my head as this topic hasn't been brought up in class yet. What is the proper solution to this dilemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use threads. Use Tasks - they are essentially the same, but.... they have a better API and are better suited for non permanent elements. Make sure to mark them as long running when running more than some part of a second.
- Tasks - you can wait on the completion of multiple. I.e. save all tasks you create (3) in an array, wait for them to finish. Finished.

For threads:

> and had main check it in a while(true),

Lack of RTFM.

OBVIOUSLY a loop without waiting will max out a CPU core.

- Easy: THread.Sleep 50ms each loop. Takes CPU way down.
- No while true - use interlocked and counter. Running from 3 down to 0.
- Read up on Signals.